# STRLEN printf on two lines?

Tags: c++, printf, strlen

Can someone explain the following occurrence to me?

```
unsigned int i;
i = strlen("testData");
printf("%d\n", i);

Output:
8
5
```

Why is it printing the extra 5?

[Update:] After reading the comment, I stupidly realized where the 5 was coming from, sorry!

Comment: Can you post a complete program?

Comment: Please take this brainfart to learn: Always provide a small, self-contained, compilable (except for questions about compiler errors, of course) program which exhibits the behavior your failing to understand. IME, most of the time creating such a repro-case makes you find the error yourself and prevents you from wasting everybody's time. And if not - well, then you've created the repro case to come here with and ask about. And now be a good citizen and delete this useless question.

Answer (score 1):

strlen stands for string length. Now, let's see... "testData".

```
1 - 't' 2 - 'e' 3 - 's' 4 - 't' 5 - 'D' 6 - 'a' 7 - 't' 8 - 'a'.
```

we counted 8.
now i is 8.

`So, printf("%d\n", i);`
prints 8.

And then later you have some code in your program which prints 5. Can't tell you why because I can't see the code

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that you have *undefined behaviour* because you are using a format specification for a signed integer (`%d`) but passing an `unsigned int` parameter. The correct `printf` call would be:

```
printf("%u\n", i);
```

Although unlikely, one possible explanation is that the undefined behaviour on your implementation results in the extra 5 being printed.

Comment: Is it really undefined behavior? Because the standard says int and unsigned int have both the same bit representation... Just curios, is it provable from the standard that this is UB?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: You have to refer to the C standard as that is where the `fprintf`/`printf` function interface is defined. ISO/IEC 9899:1999 7.19.6.1 says (paraphrased) for conversion specifiers `d`, `i`: "The `int` argument is ... " and later "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behaviour is undefined". Although I don't have C90 to hand, I don't believe this aspect has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should just print 8.There is something else beyond this code section that prints 5